# Dimension And Basis of Subspace of Function Space $\mathcal C^{m}[a, b]$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $$C^{m}\left[a, b \right] := \left\{ f: \left[ a, b\right] \rightarrow \mathbb R \vert \ f \ \text{$m$-times  continuously differentiable on $\left[ a, b\right]$} \right\}.$$

Now assume that we are given a partition $a = t_{0} < t_{1} < \dots < t_{M} < t_{M+1} = b$, where $m$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m<n$. Now let us consider the space $$S_{n}^{m} \equiv S^{m}_{n}\left(t_{0},\dots, t_{M+1}\right) = \left\{ s\in\mathcal C^{m}\left[a, b\right] \vert \ \ \left. s\right\vert_{\left[t_{k}, t_{k+1} \right]}\in\mathcal P_{n} \ \forall k = 0, \dots M\right\}. $$ I first wanted to prove that $S_{n}^{m}$ is a finite-dimensional space and I thought I could do it by proving that $\mathcal C^{m}$ is finite-dimensional, which is not the case..

**Question**: Is it correct to say that the dimension of $S$ is $(M+1)\cdot n$, because we need $n$ polynomials for each partition $\left[ t_{k}, t_{k+1}\right]$?

**Edit**: As hardmath argued, my reasoning is not quite correct, as we have the constraint that our polynomials have to be continuously differentiable at the "knots" $t_k$. To see this, I took for myself a concrete example, namely $S_{4}^{1}\left(0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\right)$. I immediately see that the dimension of $S_{n}^{m}$ is $8$, because we have two polynomials $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ of degree $4$ on the intervals $\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ and $\left[ \frac{1}{2}, 1\right]$ and two constraints, namely that $s_{1}(0.5) \overset{!}{=} s_{2}(0.5)$ and $s_{1}'(0.5) \overset{!}{=} s_{2}'(0.5)$. Since $\dim\left( S_{4}^{1} \right) = 8$, we must have $8$ basis function of this subspace. Is it possible to explicitly write down these basis functions?

Comment: suppose $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and for any $N$ and any $1\le i\le N$, take $f_i\in C^k$ such that $f_i > 0$ on $[(i-1)/N, i/N]$ and 0 otherwise. Prove those are independent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that $C[a,b]$ is infinite dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299573/how-to-show-that-ca-b-is-infinite-dimensional)

Comment: I deleted my answer in case you want to delete the post. Everything I wrote can be found in the duplicate question.

Comment: This Question is asking about how to show a subspace of polynomial splines is finite-dimensional, not about the infinite dimensionality of the ambient space $\mathscr C^m$.

Comment: The count you gave for dimension of $S$ is (with a slight mistake) an overcount.  If you only need finiteness, that is good enough.  An exact count will reduce your value by the number of constraints on the polynomial coefficients imposed by continuity of derivatives at the "knots" $t_k$.

Comment: Hi hardmath, thanks, you are right! I will edit my question because I want to consider a concrete example, and maybe write down a basis, if it's possible. I would really appreciate if you could also comment on that. Feel free to expand this and your previous comment into an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it. (And sorry for getting back so late to you..)